# Replicate Amazon RDS for non-LIVE support purpose

Tags: amazon-rds

We have a web application which is hosted on EC2 (Apache in Ubuntu) with MySQL DB in RDS (Multi AZ). We are planning to go for another application instance which will primarily be used by our support team to analyse certain LIVE issues. In order to do this, we would like to have a copy of LIVE DB data in another instance, preferably in another RDS instance. Here is our approach:

1. Get the latest RDS snapshot
2. Create a new RDS instance, and copy the RDS snapshot into it
3. Set up the application configuration to point the DB to the new RDS instance created above

Could you please share your comments on whether this approach is fine, or is there a better approach?

By the way, I checked following stackoverflow questions:

[How to copy a database using RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804913/how-to-copy-a-database-using-rds)

[Amazon RDS replica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587199/amazon-rds-replica)

In both these questions, mysqldump is suggested. But in my case the DB size will be huge, and mysqldump might slow down the LIVE performance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AWS read replicas. See http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/#Read_Replica

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning it earlier. I already have put in Read-Replica for better performance. That wont solve the problem I mentioned above, because sometimes support team tries out some heavy queries which slows down the Read-Replica too, and hence the perfromance of LIVE environment is also affected, because both LIVE and support team shares the same Read-Replica for read operations.